# iproute: disable "tc" command

Tags: networking, latency, iproute

I'm after running this command to simulate a network latency of 500ms with 100ms std deviation:

`tc qdisc add dev eth2 root netem delay 500ms 100ms`

Trouble is, I forget how to cancel this command! My computer currently has an awful latency and I don't know how to get rid of it!

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
# tc qdisc del dev eth2 root
# tc -s qdisc ls dev eth2
```

Should clear all rules on eth2.

Comment: I hope this answer will get to you before night ;)

Comment: An O/S restart also should clear the rules. When in doubt, reboot.